# Reshape () and modify_shape()

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

```
df <- data.frame(
code1 = c ("ZAZ","ZAZ","ZAZ","ZAZ","ZAZ","ZAZ","JOZ","JOZ","JOZ","JOZ","JOZ","JOZ","TSV","TSV"), 
code2 = c("NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","NAN","TSA","TSA"),
start = c("Date1.1","Date1.1","Date1.3","Date1.3","Date1.5","Date1.5","Date3.1","Date3.1","Date3.3","Date3.3","Date3.5","Date3.5","Date 5.1","Date 5.1"),
end = c("Date2.1","Date2.1","Date2.3","Date2.3","Date2.5","Date2.5","Date4.1","Date4.1","Date4.3","Date4.3","Date4.5","Date4.5","Date6.1","Date6.1"),
price = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2))
```

I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

I have so far done:

```
df <- df %>% 
group_by(code1, code2,start,end) %>% 
slice_min(price) #%>% 
group_modify()
df <- df[order(df$price),]
```

All well explained in the image but in brief:

- To group by *code1,code2,start,end* and select smallest price for each
- Reshape sending *start,end,price* to different columns (max 3 *start,end,price* per key *code1,code2*
- I understand that this can be done within **group_modify()** but unsure how

Any help so much appreciated!
Brian

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way using `dplyr` and `tidyr` libraries.

- For each group (`code1`, `code2`, `start` and `end`) calculate the minimum value of `price`.
- Create an index column for `code1` and `code2`. This is to name `start`, `end` and `price` as `start_1`, `start_2` etc.
- Get the data in wide format using `pivot_wider`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(code1, code2, start, end) %>%
  summarise(price = min(price, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(code1, code2) %>%
  mutate(index = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = index, values_from = c(start, end, price),
              names_vary = "slowest")
  

#  code1 code2 start_1  end_1   price_1 start_2 end_2   price_2 start_3 end_3   price_3
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>     <dbl> <chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
#1 JOZ   NAN   Date3.1  Date4.1       1 Date3.3 Date4.3       3 Date3.5 Date4.5       5
#2 TSV   TSA   Date 5.1 Date6.1       1 NA      NA           NA NA      NA           NA
#3 ZAZ   NAN   Date1.1  Date2.1       1 Date1.3 Date2.3       3 Date1.5 Date2.5       5
```

Note that `names_vary = "slowest"` allows to have columns in an orderly fashion (`start_1`, `end_1`, `price_1`... instead of `start_1`, `start_2` ..., `end_1`, `end_2`... etc. )

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try `aggregate` + `reshape` + `ave` (all from base R)

```
reshape(
  transform(
    aggregate(price ~ ., df, min),
    id = ave(seq_along(price), code1, code2, FUN = seq_along)
  ),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = c("code1", "code2"),
  timevar = "id"
)
```

which gives

```
  code1 code2 start.1   end.1 price.1 start.2   end.2 price.2 start.3   end.3
1   ZAZ   NAN Date1.1 Date2.1       1 Date1.3 Date2.3       3 Date1.5 Date2.5
4   JOZ   NAN Date3.1 Date4.1       1 Date3.3 Date4.3       3 Date3.5 Date4.5
7   TSV   TSA Date5.1 Date6.1       1    <NA>    <NA>      NA    <NA>    <NA>
  price.3
1       5
4       5
7      NA
```